# Does Codeigniter work well with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, frameworks

I've been using ASP.NET for a while but decided it's time to learn a PHP framework.

Looking at an article NetTuts+ It looks like CodeIgniter is the simplest, and one of the lightest and easiest ways to go.

I am however, a huge jQuery fan, and am wanting to know if jQuery integrates well with the framework?  Any experience?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly if you like CodeIgniter I'd suggest you look at Kohana instead. CodeIgniter still has PHP4 support and this in some ways makes it uglier than it needs to be. Kohana is PHP5.

jQuery works fine with either framework. The only place it really matters is for outputting JSON and that's easily done by executing it directly from your controllers.

Comment: Kohana is definitely better in my opinion. I made the switch almost a year ago. Very pleased.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter support now all PHP4/PHP5.
for jquery i'm work with jquery and CI in all my projects all it's good and it's fine to use jquery with Ci.

Info :
Kohana is gnerated from CI.